# Unreal Engine 4 linking iOS Libraries

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, static-libraries, unreal-engine4

I've started using Unreal Engine 4 for iOS games. I am trying to use UIKit as part of the HUD. When I run the profile build it fails with the error "Shell Script Invocation Error 'UIKit/UIAlertView.h' file not found".

My HUD class .h file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/HUD.h"
#include "BasicHUD.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class ABasicHUD : public AHUD
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable , Category="Custom")
    void ShowAlert();

};
```

My HUD class .cpp file looks like this:

```
#include "MyProject2.h"
#include "BasicHUD.h"

#import <UIKit/UIAlertView.h> // Error here:  "Shell Script Invocation Error 'UIKit/UIAlertView.h' file not found"

ABasicHUD::ABasicHUD(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& PCIP)
: Super(PCIP)
{

}

void ABasicHUD::ShowAlert(){

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]init];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]init];

}
```

and my build.cs file looks like this:

```
using UnrealBuildTool;

public class MyProject2 : ModuleRules
{
    public MyProject2(TargetInfo Target)
    {
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });

        if (Target.Platform == UnrealTargetPlatform.IOS)
        {

            PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(new string[] {"Runtime/Core/Public/Apple", "Runtime/Core/Public/IOS"});
            AddThirdPartyPrivateStaticDependencies(Target, "zlib" );
            PublicFrameworks.AddRange(new string[] { "UIKit", "Foundation", "AudioToolbox", "AVFoundation", "GameKit", "StoreKit", "CoreVideo", "CoreMedia", "CoreMotion"});

             bool bSupportAdvertising = true;

             if (bSupportAdvertising)
             {
                 PublicFrameworks.AddRange(new string[] { "iAD", "CoreGraphics" });
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I think I must be doing something wrong in the build.cs file but I'm not sure why it can't find the framework. How can I find UIKit with the unreal build tool?

Comment: Still don't know about this one. Anyone know if I have the right approach at least?